# Change woocommerce add to cart button to normal link

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to replace the Add to Cart button in woocommerce to a button that links to the "file url"specified for all downloadable products.      I did find some plugins like "download now", but they expect an actual file while i often entered an url pointing to an external html page as file url instead of the actual file url.

Answer (score 0):

You need external products instead of downloadable products. There are many plugins in the market which supports external products.

Comment: This seems the solution. Any clue how I automatically change 500+ downloadable virtual product into product with affiliate / external links?

Comment: Were you be able to add links there ?

Comment: yes, thanks.
I decided to delete all products and use WP all Import to reimport them with the correct type

Answer (score 0):

You can use default woocommerce feature. Follow these steps:

1. Make product Virtual & Downloadable
2. Goto Woocommerce >> Settings >> Products >> Downloadable products

   - Here for "File download method" option select redirect only

This will work as you want!

Comment: thanks but it didnt work for some reason. Either i enabled a plugin that made the add to cart link a direct download link, but it would push the url as a downloadable file or I couldnt bypass the add to cart and checkout proces

Comment: The solution which I have provided will give an expernal url access to user after purchase. Not at the time of add to cart.